# cmd: list goes over screen

Tags: cmd

For an example, if I type in "dir" in cmd for SYSTEM32, the list goes on and on.
I Enabled the scroll, but scrolling only goes for little bit.

Is there a special command or a way to control the view?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use /P option
2. You can increase cmd buffer size
3. You can redirect output to file: dir > 1.txt

Answer (score 1):

You can page:

```
dir | more
```

or you can output to a file

```
dir > output.txt
```